# Why aren't my variables pointing to the same array?

Tags: java, php, arrays

I have two classes. One that has the array (`ArrayStorage`) and the other (`ArrayConsumer`) has just a variable that will act as a simple reference to an array.

I add a new element to the array using `$my_array`. Then I check to see if the new element is visible in the `$obtained_array`. But the test fails because it cannot find the new element. They act like they were different arrays. Shouldn't they point to the same array?

```
public function testArrayMadness() {
        $arrayStorage = new ArrayStorage();
        $my_array = $arrayStorage->getArray();

        $arrayConsumer = new ArrayConsumer($my_array);
        $obtained_array = $arrayConsumer->getArray();

        $my_array[3]='c';
        $this->assertContains('c', $obtained_array);
    }
}
class ArrayStorage {
    private $my_array=[1=>'a',2=>'b'];
    function getArray() { return $this->my_array; }
}
class ArrayConsumer {
    private $obtained_array;
    function __construct($array) { $this->obtained_array=$array; }
    function getArray() { return $this->obtained_array; }
}
```

**Update:**
I did the same on test in Java, it gives me an indexOutOfBoundsException. Does that mean both php and java works the same way in this aspect or is there something wrong with my code?

```
@Test
    public void testArrayMadness() {
        ArrayStorage arrayStorage = new ArrayStorage();
        List<String> my_list = arrayStorage.getList();

        ArrayConsumer arrayConsumer = new ArrayConsumer(my_list);
        List<String> obtained_array = arrayConsumer.getList();

        my_list.add("c");
        assertEquals("c", obtained_array.get(3));
    }
}

class ArrayStorage {
    private List<String> my_list;
    public ArrayStorage() {
        my_list = new ArrayList<>();
        my_list.add("a");
        my_list.add("b");
    }
    public List<String> getList() { return my_list; }
}
class ArrayConsumer {
    private List<String> obtained_list;
    public ArrayConsumer(List<String> list) {
        this.obtained_list = list;
    }
    public List<String> getList() { return this.obtained_list; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP arrays are not objects, they are assigned by value:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = $a;
$b[2] = 99;

print_r($b); // 1,2,99
print_r($a); // 1,2,3
```

A workaround is to use reference signs `&` (a bad idea generally) or `ArrayObject`s:

```
$a = new ArrayObject([1,2,3]);
$b = $a;
$b[2] = 99;

print_r($b); // 1,2,99
print_r($a); // 1,2,99
```

Comment: or you can also use the explicit reference '&' symbol like $b = &$a; this will copy the reference.

Comment: I added more content to the question. This works the same in java?

Comment: I don't know Java, but `.get(3)` looks strange since there are only three elements in your array.

Answer (score 0):

return reference array using & operator 
something like `return &$this->my_array;`